# How to combine a variable with jQuery css selector

Tags: jquery

How can I combine a jQuery variable with some css class in the following example:

For example I can use this:

```
$("#wrapper .box")
```

But if `#wrapper` is stored in a variable, like:

```
var wrapper = "#wrapper";
```

This will not work:

```
$("wrapper .box")
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you used it as a string, not a variable. Use the concatenation operation for that.

```
$(wrapper + " .box")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and correction, if its string, how to define variable?